# sum of multiplication of two columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dot-product

I am generating a matrix in R using following,

```
ncolumns = 3
nrows = 10
my.mat <- matrix(runif(ncolumns*nrows), ncol=ncolumns)
```

This matrix indicates the co-ordinates of a point in 3D. How to calculate following in R?

```
sum of x(i)*y(i)
```

e.g. if the matrix is,

```
x y z
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

then output = `1*2 + 4*5`

I'm trying to learn R. So any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, this is called the 'inner product' or 'dot product'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the %*% function.

```
ncolumns = 3
nrows = 10

my.mat <- matrix(runif(ncolumns*nrows), ncol=ncolumns)

(my.answer <- my.mat[,1] %*% my.mat[,2])

#       [,1]
# [1,] 1.519
```

Comment: Equivalent to `sum(my.mat[,1]*my.mat[,2])`, but as a matrix.

Comment: True, thats exactly what mrn wanted.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg and Nathan G Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

you simply do:

```
#  x is the first column; y is the 2nd
sum(my.mat[i, 1] * my.mat[i, 2])
```

Now, if you want to name your columns, you can refer to them directly

```
colnames(my.mat) <- c("x", "y", "z")

sum(my.mat[i, "x"] * my.mat[i, "y"])

# or if you want to get the product of each i'th element 
#  just leave empty the space where the i would go
sum(my.mat[ , "x"] * my.mat[ , "y"])
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time. Your answer cleared my few other queries too.

Answer (score 1):

each column is designated by the second argument in `[]`, so

```
my_matrix[,1] + my_matrix[,2]
```

is all you need.